# how to integrate ESAPI with Oracle HTTP server or IBM HTTP server

Tags: oracle, esapi

Is there any way to integrate C-language specific plugin of **ESAPI** with Oracle HTTP or IBM HTTP server. I mean can we integrate C-Lang specific code with Oracle HTTP server to achieve security. It can be Java specific plug in. Expectation is to achieve Sanitize what are the steps do I need to follow?

Thanks in Advance,

Bhanu.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking... do you have a process that requires crossing a boundary from Java to say, a command line program written in C?  A web-application that's written in C?

Comment: We have done proxy server setup. We need add a plug in such that it should prevent security attacks like SQL Injection, Cross Site Scripting etc. That plugin might developed using c-lang specific or Java specific, I need integration steps for that. And we are using IBM HTTP Server as reverse proxy.

Comment: And how can achieve sanitation with IBM HTTP Server?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's not very clear what you are really trying to do here. If you are just trying to access some of the simple ESAPI validators or encoders, most of that has been implemented in the [ESAPI for C](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI#tab=ESAPI_C) project. I'd hate to recommend it because it pretty much is no longer maintained, and some of it is badly broken (e.g., the cryptography component), but if you're really desperate, it might be worth a look.

-kevin

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your response. My question  may not clear because I am new to integrating security concepts with Http server.  I need have support from third party products like mod_security to prevent SQL Injection, Cross Site Scripting etc. I didn't find proper configuration setup document for these two. My question is, Is there any way to achieve it.